# C variable being set to 0 after passing to function

Tags: c, parameter-passing

So I am running into an odd problem. I have a pointer to a struct, and I am passing it to a function. Once inside that function, one of the variables I am interested in appears to be 0, but before passing the struct to the function I check to make sure that specific variable is not 0. The weird thing is this does not happen every time, only once in a while. Has anyone ever seen something like this happen before?

Source Code:

```
if( expand->num == 0)
    return status;

status = decode( expand );

...


Status_type decode ( expand_type * expand )
{
    if(expand->cur_num >= expand->num) // Here is where my error occurs
                                       // 'num' is 0.
    {
    // Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the source code where the problem occurs, or else it will be difficult for us to help

Comment: Increase the warning level of your compiler and **mind the warnings**

Comment: Is the structure that `expand` points to statically or dynamically allocated? If it is the latter, are you checking whether the `malloc` call succeeds?

Comment: Did you retype this code, or copy and paste it? If you retyped it, was there a `==` in the if, or an `=`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the problem. There are multiple threads, and two threads were trying to access the same variable at the same time (the expand variable), causing it to be overwritten! So I had to stop one of the threads at a certain point so both wouldn't be accessing the same stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a "dangling pointer" problem:  You have a rogue pointer that is pointing to memory which does not belong to it (e.g., not an allocated instance of the type the pointer references), and somewhere the program instructs the pointer to use that "value", and the pointer is now overwriting that value (which is accidentally on the value you are inspecting).

Your symptoms match:  Intermittent, memory overwrite when it appears there should be no memory overwrite.

Those can be very painful to track down, because you need to check the integrity of *all* your pointer operations, even the ones that have nothing to do with the code you are currently looking at (monitoring).

One thing to help you track it down would be to explicitly initialize all pointers to "null" on instantiation.  This is generally not necessary, but can be helpful for debugging, because indirection-on-null will typically crash your program *right there* (which is what you want), rather than remain as a "hidden problem" as you access memory that is not yours (because pointers in C are by default not initialized to null).  So, for example:

```
int* p;   // Initialized to "garbage" memory address
```

...change to:

```
int* p = NULL;  // Force initialization for debugging, crashes on indirection
```

On the bright side, when you suffer that enough, you have habits that make you very careful with your pointers.  ;-)))

Comment: though for C I would say the usage of NULL instead of 0 is more common (even if not necessary afaik).

Answer (score 0):

Three possibilities come to mind.

1. Corruption from another task.
2. Uninitialized pointer
3. Dangling pointer

Of these three possibilities, my money (based on the current information) is that of the uninitialized pointer.

My guess is that the value the uninitialized pointer has points just far enough down the stack that when decode() is called, the memory where 'expand->num' is stored is corrupted by either copying the parameter 'expand' onto the stack, or copying the return address to the stack, or by setting up the stack frame for decode().